# How to verify if a view is visible on activity created?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a ScrollView Layout with a FAB and a Button on it. My button sets on the bottom of the scroll and when I scroll, I check if it's visible, if it is, I hide my FAB. My problem occurs when the phone screen is to big and my content can settle on the screen completely without scroll, so I get stuck with my button and my FAB overriding my button.
So, my problem is: How can I check right after the view is created if my Button is been shown to the user or not, so I can hide my FAB or not?

I've already tried using onPostCreated, onStart, onCreate and onResume. I'm using activity directly.

I verify if my button is visible this way:

```
private void controlFabVisibility() {
    if (isViewVisible(binding.btnCall)) {
        binding.fabUpList.hide();
    } else {
        binding.fabUpList.show();
    }
}

private boolean isViewVisible(View view) {
    Rect mReact = new Rect();
    binding.nsvFreights.getHitRect(mReact);
    return view.getLocalVisibleRect(mReact);
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How about using viewTreeObserver?
When you use this, you can catch the point whether the view(FAB or button) is scrolled up or down etc. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver

Comment: view has default method `isShown()` which returns boolean if visible or not, try using it.

Comment: In fact, the viewTreeObserver works, but the screen is been loaded first with some data and then the rest of the data loads and moves the button. So i'll have to make some others changes on my code. Thank you guys so much for the help.